# Custom post types display pending posts without login

Tags: wordpress, posts

I am having an issue in a custom post type ('place'). I can view the posts like "http://www.example.com/?post_type=place&p=9454" while i am logged in as any user from the front end.But i cant view the posts while not logged in and it is redirecting me to the home url.All the posts are of status pending which is my requirement.I am using directory engine and modified some functionalities. Can any one help me on this? i have spent 6 hrs already to solve this but failed.

Comment: You want to show posts in pending (unpublished) status for everyone? Basically break core WordPress functionality? Why?

Comment: It is an existing websites requirement